# Cannot write property IsFileStream

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Everytime I try to create a new Database in SQL—haven't accomplished to create any, so far. Please, help me with a detailed solution for this.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Cannot write property IsFileStream.This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1539+)&EvtID=IsFileStream&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: In the `New Database` dialog,  you should see a little button marked `Script...`.  Hit it and it should give you the SQL script it is going to execute to create the database.  Post that here.  Also run this query and post the results: `Select @@Version`.  I want to compare the creation script generated by SSMS with the actual version you are connecting to.  Finally, try to create a database manually, using the `Create Database [some name];` command and let us know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisNielsen, the  `create Database [some name]`  command works perfectly fine. When I press `Script` I get the same message as in my original post. Finally, running  `select @@Version`  gets me this message: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (CTP2) - 12.0.1524.0 (X64)   Oct  3 2013 19:00:26   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: I'm getting the very same error in SQL Server 2014 express edition. My version variable says - `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86)   Feb 20 2014 19:20:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: ) (WOW64) `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to you using older MS SQL Management studio. Download the new version in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

I faced the same issue with having SQL 2008R2 and when I installed 2019, I had the same error as you on management studio, now I'm installing new version.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server Management is unable to set up the default property while creating a database using previous version of SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes. This helped. I was accessing SQL Server 2014 express edition with SQL Server 2008 R2 management studio to create a new database.

Answer (score 5):

Select the master database and write a query to create database Example create database XYZ

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are using preview version of SQL Server 2014 (Community Technology Preview 2) which could be unstable.

You **should** use latest stable (RTM) version from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434042.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility which you can check as part of SQL Server instance properties. I'm facing this issue with SQL Server 2014 express edition also. It might be the case that the `Filestream Access Level` configuration (inside `Advanced` node) is currently disabled for your SQL Server instance. Try changing it to `Full access enabled` to resolve this issue. Have a look at the below snapshot -

[image]